# Noob Python Coder Here! Looping Column Headers Into Stats.Linregress Function

Tags: python, statistics, regression, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression

Trying to loop column headers into a function to compare r-squared values between any given column and the final column of a dataframe. Coding in Jupyter notebook.

Example:

```
r_value = stats.linregress(filename.[first_column], filename.[last_column])
```

Need to loop this logic starting with column 1 and ending with column n-1 and then print column header and the corresponding r_value(s).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm afraid this question isn't clear at all. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a pandas DataFrame this should work:

```
for col in df.columns.tolist()[:-1]:
    r_value = stats.lingress(df[col], df[df.columns.tolist()[-1]])
    print 'The r_value for {} is {}'.format(col, r_value)
```

Comment: I think I misspoke earlier. I did not create a data frame. I simply read.csv() my data file.

Comment: I'm confused now because `read_csv` is a pandas function, why not just put it in the DataFrame afterwards?